# Why aren't Jinja2 extend statements and block statements not working?

Tags: html, python-3.x, web, flask, jinja2

This is my `base.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
        {% block head %}
        {% endblock %}
   </head>
    <body>
        Outside Block
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my index.html

```
{% extends 'templates/base.html' %}    
{% block body %}
<h1> Inside Block </h1>
{% endblock %}
```

My endpoint:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('base.html')
```

And my browser displays

```
Outside Block
```

Whenever I execute my code everything except the blocks are displayed. I can even display a value by passing it as a parameter and display it as `{{value}}` or use an if condition even `include` is working. Just the block statements are not working.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the index.html instead of base.html

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Also you nee to extend 'base.html' not 'templates/base.html' in your index.html file.